# DataGridView autosizing rows with Wrapmode set lowers performance significantly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So, I have a DataGridView that has row headers disabled, wrapmode set for multiline cell text and autosize of rows to adjust to the multiline text.

In code:

```
view.RowHeadersVisible = false;
view.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
view.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

The problem is that setting the AutoSizeRowsMode property makes the view update REALLY slow, compared to not having it set.

Below is a link to more or less the same problem:

http://brianseekford.com/index.php/2010/04/01/datagridview-bug-with-the-autowrap-and-the-autorowsize-not-resizing-rows-on-scroll/

Their solution:

```
view.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;

view.Scroll +=new ScrollEventHandler(view_Scroll);

private void view_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
   //Workaround for datagrid view bug.
   ((DataGridView)sender).AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedHeaders;
   ((DataGridView)sender)AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
}
```

Now, the problem is that the row headers are disabled, and therefore my program just crashes when scrolling.

I hope anyone has a solution or atleast some idea to what i can do.

Comment: The problem is the calculation of the widest value. It iterates over all cells and rows. How about fixed widths done manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need this to autosize the rows (don't need `view_Scroll`).

```
view.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
```